# How can I draw path between two points?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've two imageview of dots in my activity. I can move one of them and I'd like to show the path between the two dots. Any suggestions?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    final float eventX = event.getRawX();
    final float eventY = event.getRawY();
    if(dotEnabled){
        dot.setX(eventX);
        dot.setY(eventY);
    }
    if(directionSet){
        direction.setX(eventX);
        direction.setY(eventY);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems, you need a 'Canvas' and an Listener for move events.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code?

Comment: @EarlGrey I was reading stuff about Canvas, but couldn't get how to use it. I've the x and the y of my dots in my activity so i tried to implement this class (edited my post).. but this is a view.. how can i use this class in my activity

Comment: Can you show me the xml file of your activity? Then I can decide what I should recommend to you.

Comment: You should let source code in, also ;) But I think I got something, will make an answer.

Comment: Oh...I just realised, I maybe misunderstood your question. What path do you want to draw? A direct line between the two points?

Comment: @EarlGrey yeah.. It's the first time I'm developping in android and don't have any clue on doing this kind of thing.. the dot called "setDirection" can be dragged all over the screen.. what I'm trying to do is to show a line joining the two dots on my screen

Comment: Okay, I get it. So you can already move 'setDirection'? Can you add the code, which lets you do that? This is the location, where you should call your DrawView. In the meantime, I'll start a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add some properties to your paint:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(30); //here you can put any width you need
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

If above code doesn't work below this part of code:

```
 super(context);
 paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
 this.x1 = x1;
 this.y1 = y1;
 this.x2 = x2;
 this.y2 = y2;
```

call `invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to extend FrameLayout, because you already use it as the outer ViewGroup in your layout.
To make this work, you have to declare two more constructors. The standard constructor is not used, when you declare an element in XML. So you have to set your Paint in all three of these constructors. To reduce redundancy, I moved this to a private method 'initiatePaint()'.
The function 'declarePath()' has to be called, when a new location for 'setDirection' is known.

```
public class DrawLayout extends FrameLayout {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    float mX1 = 0;
    float mY1 = 0;
    float mX2 = 0;
    float mY2 = 0;

    public DrawLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.initiatePaint();
    }

    public DrawLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.initiatePaint();
    }

    public DrawLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.initiatePaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
    }

    public void declarePath(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        this.mX1 = x1;
        this.mY1 = y1;
        this.mX2 = x2;
        this.mY2 = y2;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void initiatePaint() {
        this.mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        this.mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        this.mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }
 }
```

To use it in your layout, just use it instead of FrameLayout.

```
<com.example.DrawLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fl"
    tools:context="it.uniroma3.sensorlog">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/mappa"
        android:id="@+id/map"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:id="@+id/dot" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:id="@+id/setDirection" />
</DrawLayout>
```

In your Activity, you have to do something:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    this.mBackground = (DrawLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    final float eventX = event.getRawX();
    final float eventY = event.getRawY();
    if(dotEnabled){
        dot.setX(eventX);
        dot.setY(eventY);
    }
    if(directionSet){
        direction.setX(eventX);
        direction.setY(eventY);
    }
    this.mBackground.declarePath(**Here you have to pass the coordinates of your points**);
return false;
```

}

Comment: @MarkAmador I hope this works. I can't check this at the moment.

Comment: isn't working.. I've even added methods in the DrawView class (I had some issue with the xml file).. but the line isn't appearing

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, this doesn't work. I will check this as soon, as I'm able to.

Comment: @MarkAmador I think I fixed it now. You almost had it, but as you declare the view where you want to draw in XML, you have to implement two other constructors. In all of them you have to initiate your Paint. This could be circumvented when you declare and initiate the Paint locally in your 'onDraw' method. But as you have many updates while moving your point, it's better practice to use a global object and re-use it every time.

Comment: yeah I already added those constructors in the class.. but it's still not working.. I can't see the line at runtime..

Comment: @MarkAmador Okay...I checked my approach, just that I sent the path with a Button click. Can you please post the complete code of your Activity and your DrawView? A complete picture of your current situation is needed to find out, what's going on.